# How to write MainActivity and ResultActivity to add two numbers?

Tags: java, android, xml

It's a simple program adding two numbers. I have this code for the main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="@string/add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this code for the result activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ResultActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

string xml file

```
<resources>     
    <string name="app_name">MathApplication</string>    
    <string name="add">Add</string> </resources>
    ...
```

how to do the main activity and result activity in two separate files so to move on a new screen to see the result?

Comment: also post Java/Kotlin code

Answer (score 1):

you can try passing the data in an Intent in onClick() method.

first add an id in your Button.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add" />
```

In your MainActivity

```
private final String EXTRA_RESULT = "result";

private Button btAdd;
private EditText etFirstNum;
private EditText etSecondNum;
```

In onCreate() inside MainActivity

```
btAdd = findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
etFirstNum = findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
etSecondNum = findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);

btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int fisrstNum = Integer.parseInt(etFirstNumber.getText().toString());
        int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(etSecondNumber.getText().toString());

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        i.putIntExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, (firstNum + secondNum));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

When you click ResultActivity it will open and to get the value use

```
int result = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, 0);
```

And then you can set the value of the EditText

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method whenever you want to start your activity.

```
int fisrstNum = Integer.parseInt(etFirstNumber.getText().toString());
    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(etSecondNumber.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putIntExtra("result", (firstNum + secondNum));
    startActivity(intent);
```

And in your ResultActivity.class

You can access passed result using this

```
String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("result");
```